# How to split a string into couple of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

First I do not want to use boost library. I have a program which is reading a line and saving it to a string:

```
ajf938    sshd         Thu Mar 27 23:25   still logged in  c110-20-242-157.mirnd4.nsw.optusnet.com.au
```

And then I am trying to split it into 5 string. However the size of each element in string will be changed. The other string can be like:

```
jcm995    sshd         Thu Mar 27 15:18 - 15:19  (00:00)   192.131.251.2
```

What I already have is

```
pos=name.find(' ',0);
cout<<pos<<endl;
string username = name.substr(0,pos);
cout<<username<<endl;
```

And then I look for fist not character from that position:

```
find_first_not_of(' ');
```

But I think there should be other efficient way. Any idea will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

This is what I have done so far:

```
if(name.find('(',0))
        {
            string username;
            string date;
            string duration;
            string hostname;
            int val = 0;
            istringstream iss(name, istringstream::in);
            string word;
            while( iss >> word )
            {
                if(val==0){
                    username = word;
                }
                else if(val>1 && val<6)
                {
                    date +=" "+word;
                }
                else if(val==6){
                    duration = word;
                }
                else if(val == 7){
                    hostname=word;
                }
                val++;
            }
            cout<<"usename= "<<username << " date= "<<date <<" duration= "<<duration<<" hostname= "<<hostname<<endl;

        }
```

Comment: I already read this but I could not understand the meaning so I brought my own string.

Comment: Which 5 parts would you want?

Comment: first one is user name and second is sshd and third is date and forth is still login/duration and fifth is hostname.

Comment: My problem is I want the date such as 'Thu Mar 27 23:25' in one string

Comment: That's four substrings (separated on whitespace) that you need to concatenate together. That shouldn't be too hard, right?